# Интерфейсы в Java

Tags: java

Есть два интерфейса:

```
public interface RobotConnection extends AutoCloseable {
    void moveRobotTo(int x, int y);
    @Override
    void close();
}
```

и

```
public interface RobotConnectionManager {
    RobotConnection getConnection();
}
```

Как можно объяснить наличие в интерфейсе `RobotConnectionManager`  метода `getConnection()`, чей возвращаемый тип данных соответствует названию интерфейса `RobotConnection`?

Comment: Ого, тут все сложно. Но объяснить это можно так, что метод `getConnection();` интерфейса `RobotConnectionManager` возвращает экземпляр класса `RobotConnection`

Comment: Да, это понятно. Хотелось бы понять, какая связь между этими двумя интерфейсами, ведь на первый взгляд это совершенно разные интерфейсы. Почему в одном интерфейсе можно использовать данные другого, когда нет явного наследования?

Comment: А где должно быть явное наследование? Если у вас в одном классе метод возвращает `String`, то это ведь не значит, что этот класс должен `extends String` (что, кстати, нельзя сделать). Аналогично с методом в интерфейсе. Да и если на то пошло, то эти интерфейсы далеки от "совершенно разных". Что уж там - у них даже названия почти совпадают.

Comment: @Regent ну судить о каком то сходстве этих двух интерфейсов из-за похожести названий...ммм..это даже моих скудных знаний хватает, чтобы сказать, что так неправильно делать.У меня вопрос то возник, потому что пока научен только тому, что если требуется использовать в классе данные другого класса, то делаем явное "extend".

Comment: а зачем вы в интерфейсе описали метод предка, да еще и `@Override` добавили? что вы хотели этим достичь?

Comment: @MikhailVaysman для возможности использовать try с ресурсами

Comment: я понимаю, зачем вы расширили интерфейс. вопрос про другое. зачем еще раз описывать метод и добавлять `@Override`?

Comment: @MikhailVaysman в задаче это объясняется так: RobotConnection — это временно устанавливаемое соединение, которое надо закрывать, когда оно больше не нужно. Для закрытия соединения в интерфейсе есть метод close(). То есть эти интерфейсы мне уже даны в таком виде.

Comment: @MikhailVaysman ну а я хочу понять что в этих интерфейсах написано и почему это работает?

Comment: где вы взяли этот код?

Comment: @MikhailVaysman здесь: https://stepik.org/lesson/%D0%9E%D0%B1%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%BA%D0%B0-%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%BB%D1%8E%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B9-Try-catch-12773/step/7?course=Java-%D0%91%D0%B0%D0%B7%D0%BE%D0%B2%D1%8B%D0%B9-%D0%BA%D1%83%D1%80%D1%81&unit=3121

Comment: @SergioBerluskony ага, основной и единственной задачей `RobotConnectionManager` ведь не является выдача конкретного `RobotConnection` с помощью метода `getConnection`. Так что интерфейсы вообще никак не связаны, и один в другом не используется. А похожие названия - чистой воды совпадение. По поводу вашего вопроса "как можно объяснить" - потому что автор кода решил создать отдельную сущность "менеджер", которая будет отвечать за установку соединения и возвращать это самое соединение для его дальнейшего использования в коде.

Comment: @Regent это уже что-то, спасибо

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Этот одна из возможных реализаций паттерна [Фабричный метод](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A4%D0%B0%D0%B1%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%87%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B9_%D0%BC%D0%B5%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B4_(%D1%88%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%BD_%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F)). Это не классический вариант реализации, но довольно распространенный.

Класс реализующий интерфейс **RobotConnectionManager** позволяет создавать классы реализующие интерфейс **RobotConnection**. Таким образом вы можете полностью переделать процесс создания **RobotConnection**, не меня интерфейс.

Использоваться это может вот таким образом

**RobotConnection.java**

```
// добавлять public не надо
interface RobotConnection extends AutoCloseable {
    // описывать close не надо
    void moveRobotTo(int x, int y);
}
```

**RobotConnectionManager.java**

```
interface RobotConnectionManager {
    RobotConnection getConnection();
}
```

**MoonRobotConnection.java**

```
public class MoonRobotConnection implements RobotConnection {
    @Override
    public void close() throws Exception {}
    @Override
    public void moveRobotTo(int x, int y) {}
}
```

**MoonRobotConnectionManager.java**

```
public class MoonRobotConnectionManager implements RobotConnectionManager {
    @Override
    public RobotConnection getConnection() {
        MoonRobotConnection connection = new MoonRobotConnection();
        // тут может быть какой-то код
        return connection;
    }
}
```

**Dispatcher.java**

```
public class Dispatcher {
    public void doJob() {
        RobotConnectionManager manager = new MoonRobotConnectionManager();
        try(RobotConnection connection = manager.getConnection()) {
            connection.moveRobotTo(100, 100);
        } catch (Exception e) {}
    }
}
```

Вы можете вызвать метод `doJob` и передать ему любой объект, класс которого реализует интерфейс `RobotConnectionManager`. Ваш код получается "отвязанным" от конкретных классов.

```
// объект Dispatcher создан ранее и сохранен в переменной dispatcher
dispatcher.doJob(new MoonRobotConnectionManager());
```

Answer (score 1):

Метод **getConnection** вернет вам объект класса, который унаследован от **RobotConnection**.
Это будет выглядеть примерно так:

класс, реализующий этот интерфейс:

```
public class RobotConnectionManagerImpl implements RobotConnectionManager {

...
}
```

и вызов метода вернет например объект этого класса

```
RobotConnectionManager rcm = new RobotConnectionManagerImpl();
RobotConnection rc = rcm.getConnection();
```